# How to calculate line raster intersection statistics in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, line, arcgis-pro, statistics

Years ago, I lived by Hawth's Analysis Tools for spatial ecology. Since then I've been having to figure out how to duplicate the functions in ArcGIS 10.x and now ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0. In this case I am trying to duplicate the functions of the old http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/linerasterstats.php tool.

I have a 30-m raster representing dominance of a tree species (several of them actually, but let's simplify and assume it is just one) and a polyline feature class representing coldwater streams. I want to calculate the length of polyline segments within raster cells with a particular attribute (e.g., value > 0.5).

I thought I might be able to do something with converting the polylines to points and using Extract Multi Values to Points, but I couldn't figure out how to get lengths out of that. Any suggestions on that approach or a better one?